# How do i use different logging levels for different classes with log4j2?

Tags: java, configuration, slf4j, log4j2, smtpappender

In the log4j2 documentation [log4j2 java configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) the default configuration is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This will produce logging for levels ERROR or FATAL to the Console. My default logging works in the same way. The problem i run into is when I do this, though:

```
<logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="TRACE"/>
<Root level="ERROR">
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT">
</Root>
```

According to the documentation, [log4j2 java configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), this will

> eliminate all the TRACE output from everything except com.foo.Bar.

My implementation, on the other hand, works as though the

```
<logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="TRACE"/>
```

wasn't even there. It will still only print out error logs.

**Questions**

- Has anyone else encountered this problem?
- Can anyone reproduce it?
- Does anyone know how to fix it? I almost would give someone a dollar. I would definitely settle for marking their answer green, though.

Here is some information about my setup:

**Maven Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

**Other**

I am testing this in the appropriate class. I am running a JUnit test file. I've used a src/main .xml file and i've used a src/test .xml file. Both end up with the same results.

**End Goal**

My end goal is to have a specific logger send SMTP requests. I am pretty sure I know how to do this, i am just struggling with this small problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't get the logger using the same string. Once i did this, it worked:

[image]
[image]

Once i made the names the same, my program worked as the documentation specified.

Comment: What is fully qualified name of this `LogManager` class? and which jar you have used here?